# onclick a button to expand into a form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button, onclick

I have 3 buttons layed out, I want it so when the button is clicked, the box will expand with an ease, into a small form.

here is my layout

CSS:

```
        .order-box{width:800px; height:80px; margin:0 auto; margin-top:20px;}

        .order li{list-style:none;text-align:center; margin-left:70px; float:left;}
        .order li #order-btt:hover{background:#2e7794; cursor:pointer; font-weight:300;}
        .order li #order-btt{padding:10px 10px; width:160px; color:white; font-size:16px; background-color:black; opacity:0.6; -moz-transition: background 0.3s linear 0s, color 0.3s linear 0s; border-radius:3px; cursor:pointer; border-radius:6px;}
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="order-box">
        <ul class="order">
            <li><input type="button" id="order-btt" name="order-btt" value="Order Yours" onclick="orderBox();" /></li>
            <li><input type="button" id="order-btt" name="order-btt" value="New Inventory" onclick="orderBox();" /></li>
            <li><input type="button" id="order-btt" name="order-btt" value="Test Drive" onclick="orderBox();" /></li>
        </ul>
```

javascript:

```
function orderBox(){
     document.getElementById("order-btt").onclick.(this is where im stuck)                 
}
```

oh okay, so I want something like this to appear

HTML:

```
<form name="frm" id="frm" action="form-validation-advanced.html" method="get" onsubmit="return formValidation();">
<table border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" align="center" width="500">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Name:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="nm" id="nm" placeholder="Enter your name" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Age:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="ag" id="ag" placeholder="Enter your age" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                        Email:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: sorry HTML isn't appearing properly, idk if it shows buttons.

Comment: question format is off, but you'd probably want to add a class (which has a CSS animation/transition) onclick to the form element (i.e. "#order-btt clicked" .  are you really not using any sort of javascript library here?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using jquery. The simplest way is here. Add jquery inside your head tag

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

And your function will be

```
function orderBox(){
    $("#frm").slideToggle("slow");                 
}
```

your form CSS will be

```
#frm{ 
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a jsfiddle to play with.](https://jsfiddle.net/dwuepnhy/4/)

You need to explain what you want to appear when a button is pressed though.

```js
function orderBox(e) {
  var target = e.target
 alert(e.target.outerHTML);
}
```

```css
.order-box {
  width: 800px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.order li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 70px;
  float: left;
}

.order li #order-btt:hover {
  background: #2e7794;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.order li .order-btt {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  width: 160px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.6;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s linear 0s, color 0.3s linear 0s;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="order-box">
  <ul class="order">
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="order-btt" name="order-btt" value="Order Yours" onclick="orderBox(event)" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="order-btt" name="order-btt" value="New Inventory" onclick="orderBox(event)" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="order-btt" name="order-btt" value="Test Drive" onclick="orderBox(event)" />
    </li>
  </ul>
```

The above snippet contains some JavaScript that'll get you started.